# RoR/MySQL removing DISTINCT and ORDERING doesn't make any result

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a query

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.country 
  FROM table2 t2
  JOIN table3 t3
    ON t2.table3_id = t3.id
  JOIN table4 t4
    ON t3.table4_id = t4id
  LEFT
  JOIN table1 t1 
    ON t1.table2_id = t2.id
 WHERE t2.type IN ('Some') 
   AND t4.locale_id = 11 
   AND t1.table2_id IS NOT NULL
   AND t1.country IS NOT NULL
   AND t1.country != ''
 ORDER 
    BY t1.country ASC
```

And when I remove Distinct and ordering it works much faster in mysql console, BUT it working same time when I run it through Rails ActiveRecord:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
```

So that I have two questions.
First and main - why optimization hasn't result in Rails Environment?
Second - Do you know how to speed up this query more?

Comment: Replace degenerated `LEFT OUTER JOIN table1` with INNER JOIN.

Comment: @Akina degenerated? Shall we regenerate it?

Comment: @Strawberry No. I don't know correct term, it is absent in documentation. Your LEFT join acts as INNER in practive in your query and so must be replaced. (for example triangle with sides 1, 2 and 3 is really a line segment - such triangle is referred to as "??? triangle")

Comment: Well, there's no 'must' about it; it gets silently replaced whether we act or not !

Comment: did u `explain` that?

Comment: Main question - WHY OPTIMISATION DOESN'T WORK through AR